# MPAndroidChart PieChart Remove Percents

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).

I want to remove percent values on the PieChart. How can I do this?  [image: PieChart Picture]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For not drawing the entry-values, call: 
`pieData.setDrawValues(false)`

For not drawing the x-values, call: 
`pieChart.setDrawSliceText(false)`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the code bellow

```html
PieEntry pe1 =   new PieEntry(float_percent, stingdata);
entries.add(pe1);
total_values =  total_values + float_percent;

No 2: 
    
       PieData data = new PieData(dataSet);
            data.setValueFormatter(new MyValueFormatter(chart));
            chart.setUsePercentValues(true);
        enter code here
    
    No 3: 
    
     class MyValueFormatter  extends ValueFormatter
        {
    
            public DecimalFormat mFormat;
            private PieChart pieChart;
    
            public MyValueFormatter() {
                mFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,##0.0");
            }
    
            // Can be used to remove percent signs if the chart isn't in percent mode
            public MyValueFormatter(PieChart pieChart) {
                this();
                this.pieChart = pieChart;
            }
    
            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
    
    
                return mFormat.format(((total_values * value)/100)) + " %";
            }
    
            @Override
            public String getPieLabel(float value, PieEntry pieEntry) {
                if (pieChart != null && pieChart.isUsePercentValuesEnabled()) {
                    // Converted to percent
                    return getFormattedValue(value);
                } else {
                    // raw value, skip percent sign
                    return mFormat.format(value);
                }
            }
        }
```